# Handling missing values in geepack R

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a longitudinal data set which consists of subjects visiting the clinic for tb treatment. At each visit several potential predictors are recorded and there is a binary outcome for each visit whether there was a favorable or unfavorable outcome.

Some predictors have missing data at some visits while at the same visit the other predictors have complete data for that visit.

When I ran a gee model using the geepack package in R, it gave me an error and I figured out that it was the missing data causing the error because gee works on complete data.

However, if i delete an observation because of one predictor missing while others are complete, I am throwing away a lot of data. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please check here on how to ask good questions: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* have complete data, you can try imputing it. One popular library/method for this is 'mice'.

You have to be pretty careful with this approach though, because, well, making up data is a pretty big deal. In particular, real-world stuff is often missing not-at-random. Maybe extreme values are more likely to be missing, or more likely to be recorded. My impression is that how to do this right is still an open research problem.

Maybe check out the tutorial here https://datascienceplus.com/imputing-missing-data-with-r-mice-package/ or the simplified version it links to to see if this will work for your case, YMMV.